# Fragments and Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an main activity hosting three fragments. I want to pass data from another activity(which hosts a form) to one of the fragment in the main activity. Also the main activity uses viewpager to host the three fragments. How is that possible?

Comment: Have your tried anything

Comment: You should pass data from another activity to one of the fragments in your main activity. Don't forget to use a viewpager to host the three fragments.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, you'd have to write a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on data you want to pass, but I guess that packing data into Bundle instance will do the job. When you create intent to launch another activity, you can set arguments on it. And later use that arguments when creating the fragments.

Take a look at this(from Intent class):

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Bundle value)

public Bundle getExtras ()
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between activites:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra("tag", dataToPass);    
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to pass a custom object like for instance an `ArryList<CustomObject>`, your custom object class have to implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).